# First vue/webpack app and there is no webpack.config file

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

I cannot seem to get my app to load css files properly and I thought it might have to do with the fact that my app seems to be using webpack, but there is no  `webpack.config.js` file in the root.

I have `webpack.base.conf.js` and `webpack.dev.conf.js` and `webpack.prod.conf.js` but they are all in the `./build` folder.

**Is this wrong?**

Comment: Are you following a tutorial? Which one?

Comment: Nothing specific, do you have any recommendations?  I've been sorting pulling from different sources.

Comment: I thought using the `vue-cli` would alleviate some of these issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, this is perfectly right.** But since you are talking about CSS *files*, I am wondering if you are not misusing the Webpack template...

If you select this template, you are supposed to write most of your CSS code in *single file components*, along with *templates* and *scripts*. In your project, Webpack uses **vue-loader** with **PostCSS** to process your style rules. You can of course create *static stylesheets* (CSS files in the `static` folder), but you should use this feature sparingly to respect the modular nature of Vue.

(To have an example of a single file component, open `App.vue` and look at the code.)

Comment: So if I have general styles, I should just place them in the unscoped `<style>` tags in `App.vue`.

Comment: Yes, this is a possible solution. You could also define some global CSS rules in a static stylesheet that you would import manually in your `index.html`. To style specific components, however, this is much better and intuitive to use the scoped style section. :)

Comment: I was trying to import the file in my `index.html` but it couldn't find it.  Do I need to `import` it in the `main.js` file first?

Comment: If you put a `style.css` file in the `static` folder, you have to reference it like so: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/style.css">`

Comment: ahhhh  I was using the /src/assets folder.  That works!

Comment: The `assets` folder should be used for resources that can be considered as dependencies of your components. This folder is processed by Webpack. On the contrary, the `static` folder is not part of the build, so it is a great place to put some global-level resources that are not tied to specific components. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you use the `webpack` template from `vue-cli`. in this template, the `dev`, `start` and `build` npm scripts from `package.json` point to the `/build/dev-server.js` and `/build/build.js`. These two files use the [webpack Node.js api](https://webpack.js.org/api/node/) to load the webpack config from the `/build` directory.

The `webpack` vuejs-template is an advanced setup, which is not aimed at being modified. It is configurable from the `/config` directory.

I would recommend to start with the [`webpack-simple`](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple) template which is easier to grasp.

---

Also, if you use an external css file, it has to be required from javascript to be processed.

```
import '../css/styles.css'
```